# divide the number by the sum

Tags: python, algorithm, math

The user enters a number (c) and a number of decompositions (N).the program must decompose the number into a sum of numbers equal to the number of decompositions, but the difference between these numbers must not be greater than 1

for example:

```
c = 28 n = 3
print 9,9,10

c = 30 n = 3
print 10,10,10

c = 24 n = 7
print 3,3,3,3,4,4,4
```

have no idea which algorithm implements this

Comment: Well, from your examples, you have a few clues.  For c=28, n=3,  c/n=9.333; c=30, n=3 c/n=10; for c=24, n=7, 24/7 = 3.428.  The numbers used are int(c/n) and int(c/n)+1, which are going to be even and odd.   You also know if c is even or odd.   Also, check out the total number, n, and the ratio of the smaller value to n.  c=24, n=7; you have 4 '3's out of 7 total;   4/7 = 0.571... that might be a way to go.  You could brute force this, of course, by checking all combinations; (3,4,4,4,4,4,4 ; then 3,3,4,4,4,4,4, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number plus one needs to be taken `c modulo n` times. The number itself needs to be taken `n minus c modulo n` times.

If you write `c` as `c = n * q + r` with `r` smaller than n, you can rewrite it as follows:

```
c = n * q + r
c = (n - r + r) * q + r
c = (n - r) * q + r * q + r
c = (n - r) * q + r * (q + 1)
```

In code, using a list to represent the result:

```
def split_in_parts(c, n):
    r = c % n
    return [c // n] * (n - r) + [c // n + 1] * r

c = 28
n = 3
print(split_in_parts(c, n))
```

Comment: really thank you , I  thought about the algorithm for a long time, but I couldn't think of anything (